# React hooks - trigger useEffect when a nested property changes in a collection of objects

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-hooks

A page displays a list of objects `[{name:, age:}, ...]`
A second page allows to update the name of a particular object.
Then using hooks, how should I implement `useEffect()` so the list on the front page updates only when a name change has been detected?

```
const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=> {
  getAllObjects()
},[getAllObjects, objects]);
```

Comment: [Read what Dan Abramov has to say](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15924#issuecomment-521253636) regarding ESLINT for such situations

Answer (score 36):

Instead of passing the entire object to the dependency array, make sure that you only pass name. Which you can do by returning the names

```
const [objects, setObjects] = useState([])

useEffect(()=> {
      getAllObjects()
}, [getAllObjects, ...objects.map(item => item.name)])
```

Comment: Thanks, I am glad I asked I wouldnt have figured this trick out myself. 

Is it considered best practice though? 

The create-react-app linter raises a warning: React Hook useEffect has a spread element in its dependency array. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies.

Do you know if I can get rid of it without disabling the linting ?

Comment: Maybe use `objects.map(item => item.name).concat([getAllObjects])` for dependency array

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried... the linter then complained the expression is too complex and I should extract it to a variable... what I did and then pass the variable to the deps array... now it's telling me that the variable is a unnecessary dep... there might be a flaw in my design here...

Comment: @Yannick Since you know what you are doing, you can disable the lint rule for this particular line

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll start with that! Still looking forward to finding an answer that would follow Hooks best practices.... If it exists!

Comment: In my case, I needed an object, ended up with:
`...Object.keys(myObj).map(key => myObj[key])`

Comment: Object.keys(objects).map(key => `${key}_${objects[key]}`).join("_") this give you a single string which always going to be different when key or value changes in the object. Works well.

Comment: Really gr8 one, Thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Question is about efficiency, the `spread` & `map` will run on every render. It is better to manually extract the properties and only then supply them to the dep array

Comment: @keif, an alternative to extract object values:  `...Object.values(myObj)`

Comment: @MichaelG too right! Crazy how I stumbled on Object.keys and then ignored Object.values as giving me the same output with less effort.

Answer (score 7):

Check https://dev.to/aileenr/til-you-can-watch-for-nested-properties-changing-in-react-s-useeffect-hook-26nj

One can just do:

```
useEffect(()=> {
      // do something
}, [values.name])
```

> It's a fine solution if the object property always exists however if
> the property is not present at some point you get a reference error. A
> workaround in this scenario is to check if prop exists inside the hook

```
useEffect(()=> {
    if (values?.name) {
        // do something
    }
}, [values])
```

Comment: the question was how to declare dependency to a property in an array/collection... (ie. in ember.js you would do it like `todos.@each.completed`)

Answer (score 3):

```
// using JSON.stringify(object)
useEffect(() => {
   // your code here...
}, [JSON.stringify(dependencyObject)]);
```

**The best solution is to use `JSON.stringify(object)` as it won't lead to any error on the initial load or warning about the changes in size of dependency variables.**

---

```
// using spread operator
useEffect(() => {
   // your code here...
}, [ ...Object.values(dependencyObject) ]);
```

The solution with spread operator on object keys and values will cause an error if the object is null/undefined in the initial load.

```
/* 
  Also if you make a custom function that either returns the 
  values or empty array then React will give a warning about 
  the size change in dependency array.
*/
const getDependencies = (addressType: Address) => {
if (addressType) {
  return Object.values(addressType);
}
return [];
}

useEffect(() => {
   // your code here...
}, [ ...getDependencies(dependencyObject) ]);
```

So use JSON.stringyfy(object). it won't give any errors when the object is undefined or null and React won't complain about the change in size of dependency variables.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers worked for me

This is my solution:

```
const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=> {
  getAllObjects()
},[getAllObjects, ...Object.values(objects)]);
```

This way you are extracting the values from your state and once any of these values change the useEffect will be triggered

Answer (score -5):

Please add JSON.stringify for the nested object.

```
useEffect(()=> {
   getAllObjects()
},[getAllObjects, JSON.stringify(objects)]);
```

Comment: dependency array accepts variables not values